# send special characters with javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i use javascript to send usernames with javascript and $_POST method.
its work with simple usernames but with username that have special characters such as " Al[!]e$E" have problem and cannot find username in my database.

```
<div class="friend-add">

<form method="post" action="" class="form-inline">
<fieldset>
<input name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off" type="text">
<button id="add_friend" name="add_friend" type="submit" class="btn">Add friend</button>
</fieldset>
</form>
<div id="loading_m" style="position:relative; width:16px; height:16px; float:left; margin-top:-30px;margin-left:330px;background-image:url(loading.gif); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:16px 16px; display:none;"></div>
</div>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("#add_friend").click(function(){
$("#add_friend").attr("disabled","disabled");
$("#loading_m").fadeOut('fast');
$("#loading_m").fadeIn('fast');
$("#alert_m").html("");
$.post("friend_request.php", { friend_username : $("#username").val() })
    .done(function(data) {
        //alert(data);
        if (data.toLowerCase().indexOf("notexist") >= 0){
            $("#loading_m").fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $("#alert_m").html("<b style='color:#FF0040;'>This user does not exist.</b>").fadeIn('fast').delay(5000).fadeOut('fast');
                $("#add_friend").removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        }

        ......

                .fail(function(){
        $("#loading_m").fadeOut('fast',function(){
                $("#alert_m").html("<b style='color:#F00;'>Something wrong with server please try again later.</b>").fadeIn('fast').delay(5000).fadeOut('fast');
                $("#add_friend").removeAttr('disabled');
            });
     });
     return false;


});
```

Comment: pleas give more info how i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Why you should use encodeURIComponent: [When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

```
...
$.post("friend_request.php", { friend_username : encodeURIComponent($("#username").val()) })
...
```

Edit:  Use urldecode() in php to turn it back into the original string.

```
$username = urldecode($_POST['friend_username']);
```

Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php